# In Java, how to split strings without using delimiters in brackets?

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split a string by comma, but I want the comma between the brackets are ignored.

For example:

```
Input:
a1:b1, a2:b2, [a3:b3-c3, b4, b5], a4:b6

Output:
a1:b1
a2:b2
[a3:b3-c3, b4, b5]
a4:b6
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex `,(?![^\[]*\])`:

```
String str="a1:b1, a2:b2, [a3:b3-c3, b4, b5], a4:b6";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split(",(?![^\\[]*\\])")));
```

It will ignore all commas inside the square brackets.

[Sample program](http://goo.gl/oTEzV1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String str="a1:b1, a2:b2, [a3:b3-c3, b4, b5], a4:b6";
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split(",(?![^\\[]*\\])")));
     }
}
```

Output:

```
[a1:b1,  a2:b2,  [a3:b3-c3, b4, b5],  a4:b6]
```

Comment: It actually relies on a negtive lookahead that asserts that it is impossible to match a single character that is not `[` up to the first `]`. See https://regex101.com/r/mD4wW7/1.

Comment: Just a note: later, if you have different delimiters, you can replace `[` and `]` with other delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse char-by-char in order to be precise, else you can do a hack like this:

(pseudo-code)

```
1. replace all brackets by (distinct) dummy placeholders (the format will depend on your context)
2. split the (new) string by the (remaining) commas (st.split(","))
3. re-replace the distinct placeholders with the original brackets values (you will have to store them somewhere) (foreach placeholder: st = st.replace(placeholder, bracket);)
```

**Note:** On step 1, you dont replace placeholders manualy, you use a regex (e.g `/[[^]]+]/`) to replace the brackets by placeholders (and store them as well), and then replace back in step 3.

Example:

input:
`a1:b1, a2:b2, [a3:b3-c3, b4, b5], a4:b6`

step1: intermediate output: 
`a1:b1, a2:b2, __PLACEHOLDER1_, a4:b6`

step2: intermediate output:

`a1:b1
a2:b2
__PLACEHOLDER1_
a4:b6`

step3: output:

`a1:b1
a2:b2
[a3:b3-c3, b4, b5]
a4:b6`

Effectively what you do here is a *hierarchical* **split and replace**, since no regex can match context-sensitive (as no regex can count parantheses).

Comment: You mean replace commas within brackets, same change for 3

Comment: @keyser no replace the whole brackets (including the commas inside) by a distinct placeholder, **then** split by the commas remaining, and **then** replace the placeholders back with the original values

Comment: Alright, well "replace all brackets" is still a bit misleading. Maybe "between" or "within" or something.

Comment: The part that confused me is still there though

Comment: Sorry I did not get you. How to split by the "remaining" commas? For instance, "a1:b1, a2:b2, [a3:b3-c3, b4, b5], a4:b6"  TO  "a1:b1, a2:b2, &a3:b3-c3, b4, b5&, a4:b6"? Could you please give an example?

Comment: @Delibz You seem to have fallen into the same trap I did. Nikos meant that you should replace everything within your brackets with a placeholder, such as `&`, and then just split the entire string on commas and then switch back your `&`.

Comment: @Delibz, edited answer, this is guaranteed to work in every case, unlike other answers

Comment: @Delibz use `,(?![^\\[]*\\])` this to split.You need not do all this stuff.Regex has facilty for this.

Comment: @Nikos M  &  keyser   I am dealing with about 500 lines of data like this...It is impossible to replace the placeholder inside the brackets manually.  :-(   But thank you so much for you guys' help. :-)

Comment: @Delibz, you dont do it manualy, you use a regex (e.g /\[[^]]+\]/) to repace the brackets by placeholders, and then replace back, editing answer to make this explicit

Comment: @NikosM. when using regex why not use directly `,(?![^\\[]*\\])` which does not require a placeholder

Comment: @vks, this is not guaranteed to work in all cases, as explained in answer, regexes cannot account for context-sensitivity depending on context of input string, the example given in question is a dummy example, it wil not be the same, this answer is guaranteed to work in all cases. of course if the input is limited sth like a regex **will** work

Comment: @NikosM. can you show any test cases where this regex will fail?

Comment: @vks, a simple example is when a space is after the comma and the then the bracket, many more examples can be given, another is nested brackets

Comment: @NikosM. https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/53 ..........spaces dont matter.....nested breackets will need a different logice according to this answer as well.........but in rest of cases this regex is perfect

Comment: @vks, how about when the delimiter is not a comma, or other characters follow the comma (the input might be wrong). i can think of other things as well and i took the example input to just be indicative and not representative and gave a more general anser. As noted for limited input the regex **wil work**

Comment: @NikosM. https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/54 here `,` has many other characters.........